BracketError when using diffxpy for a scRNAseq experiment
I am trying to use diffxpy to do differential gene expression analysis between 2 samples (batch) in one cell type from a scRNAseq experiment and I am using the following code:
#subsetting an adata object to include only one cell type 
subset=adata[adata.obs['celltype'].isin(['Monocytes']).copy

#return data to raw format (for scalled/regressed data only)
subset = subset.raw.to_adata()

subset.X = subset.X.toarray()
sc.pp.filter_genes(subset, min_cells=10)

res = de.test.wald(data=subset,
             formula_loc= '~ 1 + celltype',
             factor_loc_totest='celltype'
                  )

But this returns the following error:
BracketError: The algorithm terminated without finding a valid bracket. 
Consider trying different initial points.

I know there is something to do with scikit-learn and tried different versions of it but didn't work.
Also there are multiple questions for this same error but for other tools and no clear answer (at least for me) on how to fix this.
Session info:
Python 3.9.20 (main, Oct  3 2024, 07:38:01) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Windows-10-10.0.22631-SP0

anndata             0.10.8
diffxpy             v0.7.4
matplotlib          3.9.2
numpy               1.26.4
pandas              2.2.3
scanpy              1.10.3
scipy               1.13.1
scvi                1.1.6.post2
seaborn             0.13.2
session_info        1.0.0
torch               2.5.1+cu118 
sklearn             1.5.2


Please post a [mre] (including the full error message and the imports).
